# C# Winform ScrollBar Question

Tags: c#

How do you get the vScrollBar to start from the bottom?

Comment: What do you mean by "turn around"? Please give more details - and more context, too (WPF, WinForms etc).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I'm guessing he means in WinForms since the question is tagged with C# and the vScrollBar is a WinForms control.

Comment: do you mean how do you get it starting at the bottom?

Comment: @Mauro, yes that's what I mean. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean how to change it into a horizontal scroll bar then you should replace it with a [hScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.hscrollbar.aspx).

Edit: I see you changed your question. To make it start from the bottom you can just set the value to the scroll bars MaxValue.

If you really need the scroll bar to be at the bottom while the value is at the minimum value you could wrap it in a custom control that hides the real value and exposes a new value that is the opposite (MaxValue - Value).

Comment: I'd like the thing to start at the bottom